# how can I find a substring searching from left of a specified location

Tags: javascript, html

let's say I have a text like

> @hello @world @guy

I want to get the position of left first occurrence of `@` according to my specified position.

If I specify the position to be `13`, I should get the position of second`@` in this string, if I specify `18`, I should get the position of third `@`.

Comment: Can't you just google it?

Comment: Can't you just loop through the string and return the index? You can also reverse the string and use `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) then, it seems.

```
str.lastIndexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
```

> The lastIndexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the last occurrence of the specified value, or -1 if not
>   found. The calling string is searched backward, starting at fromIndex.

Comment: indexOf always search string after the specified position, and i want to search the first occurence before the specified position

Comment: @KesongTse I understand. What about `lastIndexOf`?

Comment: lastIndexOf just to find the last occurence of the string after specified position, for example, If i specify the position to be 1, then it would find the third '@'

Comment: @KesongTse To me it seems it does exactly what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/uL49R/

Comment: may be my example in the last comment confuses you,let's say if I specified the position to be some value which greater than the second @ and less than third @, my want to get the position of the second one, I wonder whether I can specified the position to be negative or something, but it seems not working

Comment: @KesongTse Have you taken the time to check my jsFiddle? Could you look at it and tell me what is the expected output in that case, if not what my example gives?